# variable-specific output for MANOVA with error term?

Tags: mixed-model, interpretation, manova

I am analysing a multivariate data set of several measurements taken from a number of cells for individuals from two treatments (see example below)

```
ID TREAT CELL HEAD_A_mm2 HEAD_L_mm HEAD_W_mm TAIL_mm TOTAL_L_mm
1 1541     C   c1  5.967e-06    0.0032    0.0023  0.0336     0.0368
2 1541     C   c2  6.038e-06    0.0037    0.0021  0.0325     0.0362
3 1541     C   c3  5.537e-06    0.0032    0.0019  0.0356     0.0388
4 1541     C   c4  5.723e-06    0.0033    0.0022  0.0330     0.0363
5 1541     C   c5  6.296e-06    0.0037    0.0024  0.0352     0.0389
6 1541     C   c6  5.838e-06    0.0032    0.0025  0.0332     0.0364
```

Treatment has two levels, ID has 16 levels and measurements were taken for 40 cells per ID. ID's are different for the two treatments; they are two separate groups of 8 individuals per treatment.

My approach for analysis of some of the measurements was a mixed effects manova:

```
m.model <- manova(cbind(HEAD_A_mm2, TAIL_mm, TOTAL_L_mm)~TREAT + Error(ID) , spermmorph)
```

which works fine. However, I am now trying to get an output similar to what summary.aov gives, i.e., variable-specific effects. This works for the model without the error term

```
> m.model <- manova(cbind(HEAD_A_mm2, TAIL_mm, TOTAL_L_mm)~TREAT , spermmorph)
> summary.aov(m.model)
 Response HEAD_A_mm2 :
             Df     Sum Sq    Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
TREAT         1 3.0750e-12 3.0753e-12  12.078 0.0005448 ***
Residuals   638 1.6245e-10 2.5462e-13                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

 Response TAIL_mm :
             Df     Sum Sq    Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
TREAT         1 0.00004468 4.4679e-05  11.226 0.000854 ***
Residuals   638 0.00253914 3.9800e-06                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

 Response TOTAL_L_mm :
             Df     Sum Sq    Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)   
TREAT         1 0.00004172 4.1718e-05  10.536 0.001232 **
Residuals   638 0.00252624 3.9600e-06                    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

but not for the model with the error term

```
> m.model <- manova(cbind(HEAD_A_mm2, TAIL_mm, TOTAL_L_mm)~TREAT +Error(ID),         spermmorph)
> summary.aov(m.model)
Error in 1L:object$rank : argument of length 0
```

Presumably this has to do with the class of m.model?

```
> class(m.model)
[1] "aovlist" "listof"
```

So how do I get a variable-specific output for a manova with an error term? Any help would be greatly appreciated!